# Summarise across list columns, get first value, in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, summary, across

I have a large dataframe with some semi-duplicate entries I'm trying to merge via `dplyr::summarise`. This works fine for numeric, character, & logical columns, but not list columns.

```
mydata <- tibble(A = c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
                 B = c(1,NA,4,5,7,7),
                 C = list(1:3, 1:3, 2:4, 2:4, 3:6, 3:6))

dedupedData <- mydata %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), mean, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Works as expected;

```
dedupedData <- mydata %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), mean, na.rm = TRUE),
            across(where(is.list), first))
```

Fails differently to my dataset. The above creates a duplicate number of rows by spreading out the ranges of C, i.e. group A1 gets 1:3, A2 gets 2:4, A3 gets 3:6. For my data:

```
dedupedData <- mydata %>%
  group_by(A, B) %>%
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), mean, na.rm = TRUE),
            across(where(is.character), first),
            across(where(is.logical), first),
            across(where(is.POSIXct), first),
            across(where(is.list), first))
```

Works until I include the is.list line, whereupon it breaks with:

> Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `..5`. x 'names' attribute
> [11] must be the same length as the vector [9]

Does anyone know how to solve this? When grouped one would expect the list items to be split up as the other columns are, so the C values for group A1 should be

```
mydata$C[1:2]
```

> [[1](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html#list-columns-1)] [1](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html#list-columns-1) 1 2 3
>
> [[2]] [1](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html#list-columns-1) 1 2 3

(the first list item is double square brackets in R but not here for some reason)

And thus `first(mydata$C[1:2])`

> [1](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html#list-columns-1) 1 2 3

Which looks right, I just need to have that sent to the target cell.

Also do I need to chain the `across` lines explicitly that way? I tried `!is.numeric`, and also `is.POSIXct | is.character | is.logical | is.list`.

Thanks. Relatedly if anyone knows how to create column lists which aren't ranges that would be good - I've managed to do this through grouped summaries before, but for this reprex I copied the *R For Data Science* [example](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html#list-columns-1), but it doesn't seem generalisable, i.e. if you change the last line of mydata to

```
C = list(c(1,2,3), 1:3, 2:4, 2:4, 3:6, 3:6))
```

Then C1 will be "c(1,2,3)" rather than evaluating the comma separated terms, seemingly disallowing anything that's not a single value or range?

Cheers!

Comment: The question is not clear to me. `across(where(is.list), first))` returns first value in each `C` column which is 1:3, 2:4, and 3:6 respectively as it you are getting in the output. If that is not what you want can you show your expected output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We group by 'A', 'B', get the `first` element of the `list`, and wrap it in a `list` in `across`

```
library(dplyr)
out <- mydata %>%
  group_by(A, B) %>% 
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), mean, na.rm = TRUE), 
            across(where(is.list),  ~ list(first(.))))
```

-output

```
out
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   A [3]
#      A     B C        
#  <dbl> <dbl> <list>   
#1     1     1 <int [3]>
#2     1    NA <int [3]>
#3     2     4 <int [3]>
#4     2     5 <int [3]>
#5     3     7 <int [4]>
```

---

If we want to get the first element, another option is `slice`

```
mydata %>% 
     group_by(A, B) %>%
     slice(1)
```

Comment: That's done it - thank you, and sorry for the delay in responding. One should add to the pipe: `%>%  select(colnames(mydata))` to reorder cols to match original. Do you have any info on the tilde construction in `where`? And must one explicitly enter `(.)` in `first`? I presume this relates to the tilde. Thanks again!

Comment: @dez93_2000 Did you meant `where(~ is.numeric(.))`

Comment: Sorry, no, `where(is.list),  ~ list(first(.)`. Thanks. Also turned out that I needed the first non-null element of the list which I achieved with `across(where(is.list),  ~ list(unlist(., recursive = FALSE)))`

Comment: Along similar lines, having summarised I'm now looking to mutate to replace NULL with NA in list columns but coming up short. Trying (RHS) `~ list(ifelse(is.null(.), NA, .))` & similar but suspect I may need to integrate `unlist` somehow... Any ideas gratefully received!

Comment: @dez93_2000 You could use `map(., ~ replace(., is.null(.), NA))` within the `mutate`